# converting hive array columns into map column

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive

I have a hive table with two array columns as follows:

```
 col1        col2
a,b,c        1,2,3
```

I want to convert these two columns into map column as follows:

```
    col
  {a->1,b->2,c->3}
```

How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Explode arrays, concatenate map elements using `':'` as a delimiter, collect elements into array, concatenate array into comma delimited string, use `str_to_map` function to get map:

```
create table test_map as 
select 
array('a','b','c') col1, array(1,2,3) as col2
;

select str_to_map(concat_ws(',',collect_set(concat(c1.col,':',col2[c1.i] )))) as map_col
 from test_map t 
      lateral view posexplode(col1) c1 as i,col
```

Result:

```
map_col 
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}
```

If the number of array elements is limited then you can do without explode:

```
select str_to_map(concat(col1[0],':',col2[0],',',
                         col1[1],':',col2[1],',',
                         col1[2],':',col2[2])
                 ) as map_col
 from test_map t
```